# Invalid property list

Tags: macos, launchd, plist

I'm trying to set up a UPS solution which should shut down my Mac automatically. I've followed these instructions: [Protection from power failures! Mac, UPS, NAS & NUT](https://michaelwoodphoto.wordpress.com/2018/01/30/protection-from-power-failures-mac-ups-nas-nut/)/[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rWlouT18pw).

This requires to create a launch daemon.

I made the launch daemon plist but I get the following error /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.networkupstools.nut.plist: Invalid property list

Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>org.networkupstools.upsmon</string>
<key>OnDemand</key>
<false/>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>/usr/local/ups/sbin/upsmon</string>
<string>-D</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Essentially the plist has a syntax error - look for missing or extra formatting characters (<, >, etc).

Comment: You could consider uploading or copying/pasting the `.plist`, if you think we might spot the error more easily than you.  By the way, this doesn't relate to AppleScript, unless you can enlighten me.  Otherwise, I'll remove the `[AppleScript]` tag in a couple of hours.

Comment: There isn't an issue with the syntax of the edit - is that the contents of the actual file used?  Note that `plutil` can be used to check a property list file for syntax errors.

Comment: 1. Label≠plist name: rename the plist to *org.networkupstools.upsmon.plist* ***or*** the Label to *org.networkupstools.nut*! 2. Check whether */usr/local/ups/sbin/upsmon* exists and modify it if necessary. 3. Trailing new line at the end! Alternative: [Network UPS Tools on macOS High Sierra](https://gist.github.com/hdml/fcad80f6d483709f5e51133669e8b7ca)

Comment: I followed this instruction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rWlouT18pw and this which is actually the same. https://michaelwoodphoto.wordpress.com/2018/01/30/protection-from-power-failures-mac-ups-nas-nut/

Comment: @red_menace Your hint solved my problem. plutil said that a particular line does not have the closing delimiter and I corrected it immediately. If you change your suggestion to answer, I will definitely upvote it. Thanks a zillion.